# How to go over a dynamic object? JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an object which is created dynamically by which input fields a user filled out. It can look like this:

```
const obj = {
    “keyOne”: “valueOne”,
    “keyOneDate”: “valueOneDate”,
    “keyTwo”: “valueTwo”,
    “keyTwoDate”: “valueTwoDate”,
    “keyThree”: “valueThree”,
    “keyThreeDate”: “valueThreeDate”,
    “keyFour”: [
       “valueFour”,
       “alsoValueFour”
     ]
 };
```

As you can see there are three key pairs (e.g. `keyOne` and `keyOneDate` is a pair) and `keyFour` is an array of values.

Then I have a flag (`validObj`) which I need to set to true if at least one pair is valid (both `keyOne` and the belonging date-key have values) AND that there are no invalid keys (just one part of the pair has a value). A key-pair is also valid if both keys are `undefined`.

Also, if `keyFour` has values and there are valid pairs, the `validObj` can be true.

I tried setting up and an array with the statuses (undefined, valid, invalid) of the pairs and then use the `some` function from JS on it. But I wasn’t able to solve this in a neat way.

Here is what I tried:

```
const getKeyOneStatus = () => {
    if (keyOne === undefined && keyOneDate === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if (keyOne !== undefined && keyOneDate !== undefined) {
        return "valid";
    }
    return "invalid";
};

const getKeyTwoStatus = () => {
    if (keyTwo === undefined && keyTwoDate === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if (keyTwo !== undefined && keyTwoDate !== undefined) {
        return "valid";
    }
    return "invalid";
};

const getKeyThreeStatus = () => {
    if (keyThree === undefined && keyThreeDate === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if (keyThree !== undefined && keyThreeDate !== undefined) {
        return "valid";
    }
    return "invalid";
};

const hasKeyFourValues: boolean = keyFour?.length > 0 || false;

const statusArray: any[] = [getKeyOneStatus(), getKeyTwoStatus(), getKeyThreeStatus()];

const valid: boolean = statusArray.some((el) => {
    return el === "valid";
});

const inValid: boolean = statusArray.some((el) => {
    return el === "invalid";
});

const validObj = (valid && !inValid) || hasKeyFourValues;
```

Is it possible to just reduce `getKeyOneStatus()`, `getKeyTwoStatus()` and `getKeyThreeStatus()` to just one function?

And one problem I have is, that if hasKeyFourValues is true and there is an invalid pair, the validObj is true. But it should be false. But it should also be true if there are valid pairs and hasKeyFourValues is false.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried and why it didn't solve your problem. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Will this help? `const getKeyNStatus = (kn, kndt) => { if (kn === undefined && kndt === undefined) return undefined; if (kn !== undefined && kndt !== undefined) return "valid"; return "invalid"; };`. Then, `const statusArray = [getKeyNStatus(keyOne, keyOneDate), getKeyNStatus(keyTwo, keyTwoDate)......];`.

Comment: You are asking two things: How to simplify some code and then an actual problem. Each post should be focused on a simple issue. I recommend you delete this and ask two questions. First figure out what is wrong with your algorithm and then figure out how to remove the duplication.  Note that the code you are showing is full of undefined variables: `keyOne, keyTwo...`. Please re-read the link I sent above and make sure you post a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)